# Does "svn update" download everything or just the diff patches?

Tags: svn

I need to know a bit about subversion internals.  Anyone know why actually gets transferred during a svn update?  Say I have a huge file in the repo, with just a few lines changed.  Will svn update download the whole file or just the changes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do a simple `svn update` you will get just the difference between your current REVISION and the HEAD revision on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Only changes is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Pablo is correct, plus it will also remove any stale locks. Suggest you [read the friendly manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/index.html), it's very good.